# getting row data from bindingsource bound to listbox

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, listbox

I have a listbox like so:

```
list.DataSource = bindingSource;
list.DisplayMember = "column_name";
```

Later I would want to get the selected item's `ID` from the `DataSet` with `bindingSource.Current`. I've done this before with `bindingNavigator` and `bindingSource`, where `Current` returns a `DataRowView`, so I can cast it and I'm done:

```
Int32.Parse(((DataRowView)bindingSource.Current)["id"].ToString())
```

But in this case `Current` returns a `DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor` object, and I can't cast it.

Any thoughts will be appreciated!

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.SelectedItem` should contain the selected row's `DataRowView`. Then you can:

```
var row = (MyRowType)((DataRowView)list.SelectedItem).Row;
```

Comment: I tried:

((DataRowView)szakList.SelectedItem).Row["id"]

and I still get the error that I can't cast from DataViewManagerListItemTypeDescriptor. Am i doing something wrong?:\